# How to toggle to dark mode in Vue JS and Tailwind CSS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, vue-composition-api

I want to toggle to dark mode in Vue JS and Tailwind CSS with Dark class in tailwind, but I don't have idea what I should do. I code a little and I want to try something with v-if, like `v-if ="isDark === true"` the class(Tailwind) active dark mode like `<div class="flex justify-center mt-4 bg-white dark:bg-black">`.

Obs: I active dark mode in tailwind.config.js with darkMode: 'class'

Here's what I code:

```html
<button href="" class="px-2 mb-1" @click="isDark = !isDark">
  <img src="../Assets/Icons/moon.svg" alt="" class="w-6 h-5 hidden lg:flex md:flex" v-if="isDark === true">
  <img src="../Assets/Icons/sun.svg" alt="" class="w-6 h-5 hidden lg:flex md:flex" v-if="isDark === false">
</button>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  setup(){
    const showSidebar = ref(false)
    const stayInDropdown = ref(true)
    const isDark = ref(true)
    return{
      showSidebar,
      stayInDropdown,
      isDark,
    }
  },
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added `:class="isDark ? 'dark' : ''"`in my div who contains all my code and work's!

Answer (score 0):

Try to watch the `isDark` property and add/remove the `dark` class from the body  element :

```html
<script>
export default {
  setup(){
    const showSidebar = ref(false)
    const stayInDropdown = ref(true)
    const isDark = ref(true)

     watch(isDark,(val)=>{
     
      val?document.body.classList.add("dark"): document.body.classList.remove("dark")
   })

    return{
      showSidebar,
      stayInDropdown,
      isDark,
    }
  },
</script>
```

Comment: Where I put this code? I try in scrip but the page crash ```const isDark = ref(true)
    watch(isDark,(val)=>{
     
      val?document.body.classList.add("dark"): document.body.classList.remove("dark")
   })
```

Comment: please check my edited answer

Comment: The page continue crashing. obs: I want isDark toggle all the page, but the property aren't in all div's. if you want we can continue this in discord